# pip install nsenter times out in alpine docker container

Tags: python, docker, alpine-linux, nsenter

I am using alpine:3.7 and i try to install python nsenter package:

```
FROM alpine:3.7
MAINTAINER blah-blah <blah@blah.com>

RUN echo "http://dl-2.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.7/main" >> /etc/apk/repositories && \
    echo "http://dl-3.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.7/main" >> /etc/apk/repositories && \
    echo "http://dl-4.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.7/main" >> /etc/apk/repositories && \
    echo "http://dl-5.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.7/main" >> /etc/apk/repositories

RUN apk --update --no-cache add python py2-pip docker
RUN pip install --upgrade pip setuptools nsenter
```

and it is stuck on:

```
 Collecting nsenter>=0.2 
 Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a5/46/1bfe9cca7f2e12cb2d7d9082b14feb785bc63628fb795a34d53ef57a8b93/nsenter-0.2.tar.gz
```

Even if I try to install it from within the container:

```
pip install nsenter -vv
Collecting nsenter
1 location(s) to search for versions of nsenter:
* https://pypi.org/simple/nsenter/
Getting page https://pypi.org/simple/nsenter/
Looking up "https://pypi.org/simple/nsenter/" in the cache
No cache entry available
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.org
https://files.pythonhosted.org:443 "GET /packages/a5/46/1bfe9cca7f2e12cb2d7d9082b14feb785bc63628fb795a34d53ef57a8b93/nsenter-0.2.tar.gz HTTP/1.1" 200 4324
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a5/46/1bfe9cca7f2e12cb2d7d9082b14feb785bc63628fb795a34d53ef57a8b93/nsenter-0.2.tar.gz
Downloading from URL https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a5/46/1bfe9cca7f2e12cb2d7d9082b14feb785bc63628fb795a34d53ef57a8b93/nsenter-0.2.tar.gz#sha256=876a18cb03de85948e4cd72fd4cfda4879561b7264f5722603f6437d452a25cb (from https://pypi.org/simple/nsenter/)
Ignoring unknown cache-control directive:
Ignoring unknown cache-control directive: immutable
Updating cache with response from "https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a5/46/1bfe9cca7f2e12cb2d7d9082b14feb785bc63628fb795a34d53ef57a8b93/nsenter-0.2.tar.gz"
Caching due to etag
Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-install-iLC2FC/nsenter/setup.py) egg_info for package nsenter
Running command python setup.py egg_info
```

I even tried to wget the nsenter from pypi repository https://pypi.org/simple/nsenter/ and used to install:

```
python setup.py install
```

The README.rst says:

```
Requires Python 2.6 or higher
```

But for installation it uses only python3/pip3:

```
Install from PyPI::
sudo pip3 install nsenter

Install from git source::
python3 setup.py install
```

Any ideas how to install nsenter without having to change my python version?
Maybe this could be a bug that needs to be opened upstream?

Comment: Why arent you using `FROM python:2.7-alpine` ? Should be faster than doing this. Either way im still testing it like you have it.

Comment: Update, I was able to build your image exactly as you put it up -- no issues. https://gist.github.com/kingbuzzman/0da1a7392e83e172b07923b0371c11b2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was something related to the infrastructure! I needed to add --mtu=1450 to my docker service because probably some dependency from nsenter needed bigger packets...
Now it runs successfully!